# How to hide a child element as default and show it when users over over a parent element with material ui(react.js)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want a child element hidden as default and when users hover over a parent element, show the child element with styling.

How can I do that with material-ui?

```
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";

export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid
        item
        sx={{
          p: 4,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
            cursor: "pointer",
            "& .addIcon": {
              color: "purple",
              opacity: 1
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        <AddIcon
          className="addIcon"
          sx={{
            height: "50px",
            width: "50px",
            color: theme.palette.grey[400],
            mb: 2,
            opacity:0
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Can't I overwrite/apply the same property? for this case `opacity`.

I tried to switch from `opacity: 1` to `opacity:'inherit'` or other property when it hovered but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the "display" property ?

```
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";

export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid
        item
        sx={{
          p: 4,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
            cursor: "pointer",
            "& .addIcon": {
              color: "purple",
              display: "block"
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        <AddIcon
          className="addIcon"
          sx={{
            height: "50px",
            width: "50px",
            color: theme.palette.grey[400],
            mb: 2,
            display:"none"
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: `display: none and block`   worked! Thank you!